# Is there a way to have my service worker intercept fetch requests coming from a client-side SvelteKit load function? (+page.ts)

Tags: service-worker, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to have a service worker intercept fetch requests coming from a client-side SvelteKit load function. The network requests are being made, but the fetch event is not being triggered.

The fetch request from the load function is going to `/api/allTeams`, which is cached as reported by chrome devtools, but like I said, it's not getting intercepted. All the function does it fetch the data, and return it in a prop.

Also, every couple minutes I run `invalidateAll()`, to reload the data, and even those requests aren't being picked up by the SW.

Thanks!

--reese

`src/service-worker.js`:

```
import { build, version } from '$service-worker';

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
  
  console.log("fetch")

  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(function () {
      return caches.match(event.request);
    }),
  );
});



self.addEventListener('install', async function (event) {
  event.waitUntil(

    caches.open("ccs-" + version).then(function (cache) {

      cache.add("/api/allTeams")
      cache.addAll(build)

      return;
    }),
  );
});
```

`src/app.html`:

```
    <script>
        const registerServiceWorker = async () => {
            if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
                try {

                    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service-worker.js", {
                        scope: "*",
                    });

                    if (registration.installing) {
                        console.log("Service worker installing");
                    } else if (registration.waiting) {
                        console.log("Service worker installed");
                    } else if (registration.active) {
                        console.log("Service worker active");
                    }

                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(`Registration failed with ${error}`);
                }


            }
        };

        registerServiceWorker()

    </script>
```

`src/+page.ts`:

```
export async function load(request: Request) {

   const searchQuery = new URL(request.url).searchParams.get("q")
   
   const apiUrl = new URL(request.url)
   apiUrl.pathname = "/api/allTeams"

   const req = await fetch(apiUrl)
   const data = await req.json()

   return  {data, searchQuery};
    
}
```